# Plotting set of functions with individual regionfunctions using PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, legending, mapthread

In this simple example, a set of functions is plotted using `PlotLegends` functionality.

```
funs = {Sin[3 x], Cos[2 x], Tan[x]}
Plot[ funs, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

For a distinct list of regionfunctions

```
regfun = {Function[{x, y}, x y > 0] ,Function[{x, y}, y  < 1/2],Function[{x, y}, x > Pi/2]};

Show@Table[Plot[funs[[i]], {x, 0, Pi}, RegionFunction -> regfun[[i]]], {i, 1,Length[funs]}]
```

[image]

I would like to use `PlotLegends` too!

My question:

Is there a simple way of using "list of regionfunctions"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
funs = {Sin[3 x], Cos[2 x], Tan[x]};
regfun = {
   Function[{x, y}, x y > 0]
   , Function[{x, y}, y < 1/2]
   , Function[{x, y}, x > π/2]
   };
cols = ColorData[97][#] & /@ Range@Length@funs;

Show[MapThread[
  Plot[#1, {x, 0, \[Pi]}
    , RegionFunction -> #2
    , PlotStyle -> #3
    , PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{#3}
      , { StringForm["`` on ``"
        , ToString@TraditionalForm@#1
        , ToString@TraditionalForm@#2]}]
    ] &
  , {funs, regfun, cols}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Syed Clever, thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure. I ended up learning a few things myself esp. the interaction of `ToString` with `TraditionalForm`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `funs` and `regfun` to construct [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html)s and `Plot` them:

```
condexprs = MapThread[ConditionalExpression[#, #2[x, #]] &]@{funs, regfun}

Plot[condexprs, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: elegant@kglr, and welcome back:-)

Comment: thank you @valarmorghulis

Comment: @kglr Very tricky and compact, thank you!